# Error in uploading file into android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I have recently updated to the Intel HAXM 6.0.4. The problem is I could not upload my app into the emulator even though the emulator is showing up. May I know what is the problem? The command of HAXM below seems to work correctly. However, there is nothing happen in the uploading window. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfTEw.png)

`Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554`

Answer (score 0):

you just update Google Repository too and close your android studio and restart it, this work for me